# Lightest way to run IIS on Mac?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, iis-7, mono, virtual-machine

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 app that I would like to run on a Mac machine. I would hate to run a full blown Windows virtual machine when all I really need is IIS7 to run the MVC app. What is the lightest way to run this (VirtualBox, Parallels, IIS7 Express, etc)? Really my goal is to code the Javascript/client-side of the app on my Mac and I am trying really hard not to do my development on a Windows machine :)

Comment: Do you really need IIS? Have you tried running in apache/mod_mono?

Comment: It wasn't clear, but it looked like mono is a few versions behind and can only run MVC 2 or 3.

Comment: Use a windows machine. I'll never understand why people feel the need to shoot themselves in the foot repeatedly like this. Mono doesn't support the latest greatest .NET stuff, it never will keep pace with MS releases. You can either wait until it does, or use a MS dev platform.

Comment: We develop on Macs at my job but we develop only ASP.NET MVC apps in the MS stack. We use VMWare Fusion to run our Windows dev VM and it runs without flaw just as fast as if I were natively running Windows. It even supports multiple monitors in full screen. 2 environments in one with no loss in productivity

Comment: Updates on Mono's ASP.NET MVC support can be found at Miguel's blog, http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2012/Mar-28.html

Comment: @AlfalfaStrange, I am using Parallels but the Mac gets really hot and fan goes crazy. Do you experience this with Fusion for long periods (like half a day to a day)?

Comment: No I don't, but if it means anything I also have an SSD, 8GB of RAM. and i7 proc. Not sure if that would make a difference between what you have or not

Comment: Let me go old man curmudgeonly on you and say that if you *have* to have your backend running to code the front, you haven't encapsulated properly. I usually code client-side against static JSON (or other) files; speeds things greatly. Seems you could use Mono's debugger if you *had* to go against something live for a while. But is there no database? B/c quickly I'm joining @Chris on this one. (Full, hypocritical disclosure: That said, I use VMWare to run IIS & develop against Windows on Mac, and XSP looks *very* interesting.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**BEWARE: The below answer is very old and I don't delete it just for historic purposes. These days I would recommend to install ASP.NET Core along with .NET6. After you have set that up, there are different ways to expose your web port in production, such as NGinx reverse proxy, or Kestrel or other things that I haven't researched much these days.**

Follow [this link](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2012/Mar-28.html) (provided by @LexLi in a comment above) to know how to set up your MVC environment.

With regards to IIS, as far as I know it cannot be done. You should use the native web server of your operating system. IIS doesn't run on Mac, so I guess you should try Apache, and then install module "mod_mono".

Or if that gets too hairy, just use the standalone mono web server called XSP.

Or run FastCGI, or nginx.

It is all explained here: http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET

Answer (score 7):

I use Parallels, and although their software was poor a few years back, it's now lightyears ahead of VMWare in stability and performance. Parallels Desktop 7 for mac is awesome.

My only computer is a MBP, yet I develop [software for IIS](http://imageresizing.net). I run Parallels in Coherence mode, and I essentially have VisualStudio as just another mac app. And since I'm only running one app in the VM, it's way more stable than a normal PC install. I actually haven't rebooted it in 2 months so far!

Only caveat - you want to dedicate 2-4GB of ram to the VM to prevent paging, so you should try to get more than 8GB if you're  a polyglot developer. Having multiple IDEs on multiple OSes can be heavy, and when you add the memory-hogging yet blazingly fast Chrome to the mix, you'll hit that ram limit often...

Answer (score 1):

`xsp` is a alternative for IIS in Mac, that can run basic capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) with a copy of [windows home](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10) (free with "I don't have key") and installed [visual studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) on it (community version). And IIS Express works just fine, TFS repos work too.

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded Mono on Mac from https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/.
After the installation open terminal on VS and run the command xsp, it will start listening on a port, build your project and you can see it running on the browser selected.