# Windows Authentication asp.net core development on Mac

Tags: visual-studio, iis, asp.net-core, vs-community-edition

I've moved from a windows machine to a Macbook so I've moved from VS Community to VS Community for Mac.

I already have applications built in Asp.net Core 2.1 with Windows Authentication which does not work when debugging on the Mac because it does not have IIS from my understanding and I cannot move to Individual Accounts Login.

Is there any work around for this without having to publish the code to test code?

My current setup in VS Community for Mac and Docker for SQL Server

Comment: Googling "IIS on Mac" results in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765309/lightest-way-to-run-iis-on-mac which points at https://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/aspnet/ . I would be suprised if you could get windows authentication working though.

Comment: Would it be possible to use Impersonation within the dev environment, essentially debugging as a way to test with windows authentication without actually having it?

Comment: Maybe. I don’t know anything about Macs. I do know that if you’re not connected to a domain then you need to use NTLM. And you should be able to enter the NTLM credentials straight into a browser. I seem to recall doing that many years ago but it used IIS

Comment: There is no Windows authentication on macOS, so you cannot achieve your goal without changing authentication method.